# Should I take cash or use debit card in Prague during Covid?

Tags: covid-19, money, restaurants, czech-republic, prague

hoping someone can help me.

I am taking my wife away on the 8th of December for her birthday.

Before the pandemic I would normally get local currency in cash. Because of Covid I unsure if restaurants, bars and shops are currently accepting cash?

Would it be better to use a debit card (although I would rather not have extra charges!)

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, but do check out the Covid rules, as more and more countries have (partial) lock downs. And going would not be fun if all restaurants and so on are closed.

Comment: Unless you go to small villages the cards are accepted very very often. Just look at the at front doors if there is the card schemes symbol.

Comment: In fact some brands prefer cards over cash because of Covid.

Answer (score 3):

I was there few weeks ago. Both are perfectly fine. For small purchases like street food or drink, it seems like cash is the "normal" way of operating. If I recall correctly some stores may have a "minimum" for using a credit card, maybe $5 or thereabouts. In most stores you can pay either in Czech Krona or Euro.

No one wore masks outside and even inside mask wearing was kind of spotty. Officially you are required to carry proof of vaccination or recovery but I don't think anyone ever asked for this.

CAVEAT: This was about three weeks ago and Covid cases are rising sharply in the Czech Republic. Current situation and rules may be different now. Check out: https://www.pragueexperience.com/information/coronavirus.asp

Comment: Thank you Hilmar, will have a look at that link. My preference is local cash but just don't want to be caught out and not be able to use it.... sounds that it will be ok though 